# Macbook only boot on target disk mode

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, boot

Well, when I try to boot it stucks on grey screen with thunderbolt and firewire symbols, it is always trying to boot on target disk mode, I believe its a driver problem with the built-in keyboard, before shuting the computer down it usually got the "t" key held pressed by its own, i tried removing the key and claening under it but the problem remains.

OS X commands for boot don't work, and plugging another keyboard with the USB port doesn't help neither because it takes to long to recognize the external keyboard. Is there a way I can deactivate the built-in keyboard even with no access to the OS?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you can give this temporary solution a try.

Push down every numerical keys or so many keys you can with your fingers, also try other keys than numerical. It may interrupt the boot process to recognize the "t".